# Simple loop for length

Tags: jquery, loops

Yes this should be easy, though it is early in the AM and for some odd reason this is not interpreting correctly. I had two different codes one for different reasons. First code is below

1st Code:

```
$(function(){
    var who = $('.buttonwrap').each();
     var what = who.children('ul');
      var when = what.children('li');
  for (var i = 0; i>when.length; i++ ) {
          $('.counter').html(when[i]);
        }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/apugal/1/edit

Then I had this for a different reason

```
 $(function(){
   $('.topic_button').each(function() {
     var s = $(this).attr('value');
   $.get(s, function(data) { 
     var elem = $(data).find('.main-content .statused tr.bg').length;
   $('.counter').text(elem);
      }, 'html');
      });
     });
```

Same html markup as http://jsbin.com/apugal/1/edit but different code.

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong, I will try to work this code myself. If it becomes a pain I'll ask for more help. Thanks

EDITED SECOND CODE!

Comment: i>when.length looks incorrect to me surely that should be <

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe, still working on writing loops instead of using the jQuery each function sense its built in a library I'd rather learn a loop sense it runs faster :) though somethings I get this error like unexpected string < ?

Comment: Explain: 1. What the code is supposed to do? 2. What you actually see? 3. What is the relation between the two bits of code?

Comment: @undefined first code was trying to read how many li's are in the buttonwrap. The second code is trying to get `.main-content .statused tr.bg').length;` of the url specified in the value attribute. So first button value ="/c1-category" and then it would count using the ajax and replace the html of `.counter` so if there are 8 topics it would write in 8

Comment: @interjay Two different codes for two different reasons. 1st code reads how many lis are in the wrapper. Second read comment above please. The second code worked once, and it was doing ok, except it was making all of the .counters the same number meaning not looping correctly.  There is no relation except that they will be in the same function since some of my buttons will read the topics count and the others will be dropdown unordered list

Comment: Please re look at second code as I updated what I was actually using.

Comment: JC yes that is for the first code. The second code I didn't make a jsbin for since I just am pressed for time. Would you like a bin for the second code?

Comment: I might have given my answer below prematurely....did not see this comment :(

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the jsbin link you provided.

For the first code, I did the following and it seems to do what you're wanting. (at least another way of looking at it ;) )

```
$(function(){
  var who = $('.buttonwrap').each(function(){
    var what = $(this).children('ul');
    what.each(function(){
      var when = $(this).children('li');
      $('.counter').text(when.length);
    });
  });
});
```

For the second, it seems you're trying to extract the value from each `.topic_button` div using `$(this).attr('value');` however, when viewing the markup, there's no 'value' attribute to get a value.

From the html given (just took the first one):

```
<div class="buttonwrap">
  <div class=".topic_button">topic 1</div>
  <ul>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>f</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, for classes in HTML, and this probably was a typo, just use `class="classname"` with no period in front of the name.

Comment: lol yes just a typo :) on the class. I was trying to hurry and make some markup oops. And yes there is a separate code for this. I'll make a bin... http://jsbin.com/otetah/1/edit  you'll have to click on each, this is quick so don't mind the minified :)

Comment: please take a look at updated bin here... http://jsbin.com/apugal/8/edit 

For second code here ...
http://jsbin.com/otetah/1/edit

Comment: First code worked, except the loop is wrong and copying all the same numbers just like I had problems with before.

Comment: I see the value attributes now. However, when using a jQuery `$.get` call, it requires (in your case) `var s` to be completing the url path for the content you're trying to get.

If your calling (taken from the first value) `c1-tutorials`, then your path should be `http://www.yoursite.com/{whatever-page-level}c1-tutorials`. It might need html or php or some file extension on the end (if applicable).

I'd check your paths for your ajax calls.

Comment: For the first code, the markup only showed one `.counter` div so I assumed you wanted the last value written there. If you want a count in each topic_button you would want to call it's specific counter span tag such as `$('.topic_button span.counter')...`

hope that helps

edit: use $(this) of course

Comment: Ok I got the first code to work nicely now that I'm more awake haha. http://jsbin.com/apugal/10/edit

Just not quite sure to do with the second code, I'll have to play around with that as well I suppose.

Comment: If you have FireFox, try using Fire Bug and view the ajax calls from the concsole. You'll see what response is coming back. The paths might not be correct, but I could be wrong. I would start there before going further into the data parsing.

Comment: ok. I use all browsers to check compatibility. I never see ajax calls though. Is there something I type in? or what. When I inspect the elem it just just exactly what my html markup was written. So...

Comment: If you have Fire Bug installed for Fire Fox, hit F12. It might have the console tab selected by default otherwise select it. Refresh your page. You should then see each get request.